# Can I make a #define and use it in a throw?

Tags: c++, macros, try-catch

Can I make something like this?

```
#define N_VALID "is not a valid ID"  
...  
throw N_valid;  
...  
catch(char *message){  
fprintf(stderr,"%s",message);}
```

Comment: A #define does no more than replace N_VALID with the code you have there, if it works inline without the #define it should work with it.

Comment: Something like that, yes. Didn't you try before asking? What problem are you having with it?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Seeing it work doesn't mean it's a good idea. On most modern compilers, this "works": struct X { void Y() { cout << "Hi!"; }}; int main() { ((X*)(NULL))->Y(); }, in that you see the "Hi!" output, but just because you see what you wanted to see doesn't mean you haven't entered Undefined Behavior-land.

Comment: Yes, @Bill, but the question doesn't ask whether it's a good idea. The question just asks whether it's possible.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Fair enough. I would just be cautious about teaching the mindset of "it compiled and produced the behavior I wanted, therefore it is good!"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, except that you are throwing a `const char *`, not a `char *`: https://ideone.com/UsnitG

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

#define N_VALID "is not a valid ID"

void function_throws()
{
  throw N_VALID;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        function_throws();
    }
    catch(const char *message) // <= Note the const here!
    {
        cout << message << endl;
    }
}
```

However, Joel is correct that you should avoid doing this.  If you really want to use a macro here, try using it as an argument to a std::exception object: https://ideone.com/Dsx1RF

```
void function_throws()
{
  throw invalid_argument(N_VALID);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        function_throws();
    }
    catch(const invalid_argument& ex)
    {
        cout << "invalid_argument: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok,i have something like this      
  
if(...){        
char errormsg[1044];      
strlcat(errormsg,buffer,1024);       
strlcat(errormsg,"is not a valid ID");        
throw errormsg;      
        
Ok,i have analyzed the code and there could be a buffer overflow there,even if is enough space,i want to get rid of it,and that was one of my ideas

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
#define N_VALID "is not a valid ID" 

throw N_VALID;
throw "is not a valid ID";
```

The bottom two lines above are literally identical in the eyes of the compiler, once pre-processing has completed.

Answer (score 0):

This is legal but immoral.  You should ALWAYS throw an object so that your clients can handle your errors individually, rather than having a giant if statement in one catch.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I would say that intentionally writing code to make extensibility and maintenance harder is immoral.

Comment: It is immoral to cause yourself and others unnecessary pain and suffering, and creating unmaintainable code is just that.

Answer (score 0):

The #define directive works by replacing a tag with another tag in your code before the application is compiled. Thus, if you can do this:

```
throw "is not a valid ID";
```

you can do this:

```
throw N_VALID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  Remember, the pre-processsor runs before the compiler and will replace the N_VALID with "is not a valid ID"